# change font family of a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**I need to change the font-family of the text contained in a variable in JavaScript**

This is my js code:

```
var TextInsideTd = ctrl.innerHTML;
      var TextInsideText = document.getElementById('musicnotes')
      if ( ctrl.classList.contains('psaltica') ) {
        var txt = "<span>"+TextInsideTd+"</span>";
        var result = txt.style.fontFamily = "EZ Psaltica" ;
        console.log(result);
        TextInsideText.innerHTML += result ;
```

I am getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: txt.style is undefined
```

How can i fix it

Comment: As far as I can see, `txt` is String, not HTMLElement. That's why you get such kind of error.

Comment: Strings in JS variables don't have any specific font family, do you mean you want to set and get the font family of `span` tag in that string? If that's the case, that's also not possible before the tag is actually inserted to the DOM as an element, or at least is created as a parentless element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var TextInsideTd = ctrl.innerHTML;
var TextInsideText = document.getElementById('musicnotes')
if ( ctrl.classList.contains('psaltica') ) {
  var result = "<span style=\"font-family: EZ Psaltica;\">"+TextInsideTd+"</span>";
  
  TextInsideText.innerHTML += result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Are looking for something like this ?**

```js
var ctrl =  document.getElementById('amoos');
var TextInsideTd = ctrl.innerHTML;
      var TextInsideText = document.getElementById('musicnotes')
      if ( ctrl.classList.contains('psaltica') ) {
        var txt = `<span style='font-family:EZ Psaltica; color: green'> ${TextInsideTd} </span>`;
         
        TextInsideText.innerHTML += txt ;
        }
```

```html
<span id="amoos" class="psaltica">Amoos</span>
<hr/>
<span id="musicnotes">Orange Color</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `var txt = "<span>"+TextInsideTd+"</span>";` is not DOM object.
It is text.
So you can not add object property to text.
First you need to place text on DOM object and then aplay property **style** to it.

```
var TextInsideText = document.getElementById('musicnotes')
  if ( ctrl.classList.contains('psaltica') ) {
    var txt = "<span>"+TextInsideTd+"</span>";
    TextInsideText.innerHTML = txt;
    TextInsideText.style.fontFamily = "EZ Psaltica"t;
}
```